# find() or children() to search top-level children only for a style?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to find if a child element exists which has either of two class styles applied. My code looks like this:

```
var listOfMatchedResults = $("#parentList").find(".myStyle1, .myStyle2");
```

My styles are defined like this:

```
.parent li, .myStyle0 {
}

.parent li.myStyle1 {
}

.parent li.myStyle2 {
}
```

I don't need to traverse more than one level deeper than the children level, like:

```
<ul id='parentList'>
    <li><p>foo</p><p>grok</p></li>
    <li class='myStyle2'><p>Here</p><p>I am!</p></li>
    <li><p>foo</p><p>grok</p></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not clear as to what find() is doing, is it going into each of the paragraph elements too? I just need it to traverse the top-level children - is there a way to specify that?

Thank you

Comment: *"I'd like to find if a child element exists"* Seems like you're just testing for the existence of one of the children. Is that right, or do you actually want to return the child? My answer gives you ways to perform a test for existence.

Answer (score 13):

> I'm not clear as to what find() is doing, is it going into each of the paragraph elements too?

**yes it does**

> I just need it to traverse the top-level children - is there a way to specify that?

**yes, use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**

From API Doc:

> The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Comment: @Mvan - Pithy and concise are synonymous. :o)

Comment: If I remember correctly, it's a quote from "Angela's Ashes" by Frank McCourt. I might be able to look it up, the e-book should be somewhere. *searches*

Comment: @Mvan - Just give you a little bit of a hard time. ;o)

Comment: "Pithy, Clarke, but adequate."